# Raft Leader election , When the candidater receive a voteRequest with Higher Term, what should the candidater do?

Tags: distributed, consensus, raft

I know that when the candidater receive a heartbeat with higher Term, it will convert to follower of the new leader. but there is a case the Raft paper do not talk about.

When the candidater receive a voteRequest with Higher Term, what should the candidater do?

Answer (score 0):

If a Candidate receives a RequestVote RPC with a term higher than its own, it should convert to a Follower and grant its vote for that term to the node requesting it (assuming the log matching property is satisfied and there are no other RequestVote RPCs with an equal or higher term).